# Cutsom X-axis range for differnet series- highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working on high chart using [this](http://jsfiddle.net/50a8ajLv/) example.

I have four different series, and I need to show them as (0-25), (26-50), (51-75), (76-100).

Lets say:

```
series1 = [12,58,65,02,08,100]
series2 = [67,58,23,70]
series3 = [112,558,559,40]
series4 = [56,65,41,91,73]
```

Now I need to show series1 on x-axis ranges from (0-25), and series2 on range from (26-50) and so on for other two series. Is there any work around for these type of series in high chart, I have look into docs but couldn't find.

any hint will be helpful here. Thanks

Comment: Since `series1` has `6` elements and you want to show it in x-axis ranges from `(0-25)` do you want 6 random elements from `0-25` ?

Comment: series 1 can plot anywhere between 0-25

Comment: It seems that you need to just define x values just as it is in your linked demo - http://jsfiddle.net/wn6db95n/. If it is not, explain the problem with more details.

Comment: what if series1 has more than 25 values?

Comment: Then you would need to put your x values with less than 1 interval. Say there was 50 points, you would put them `[0, 0.5, 1, 1.5,...]`